# Seneca or hydra for nodejs microservice architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing an application in NodeJs with microservice architecture. Which is the best framework to use?

Comment: this is opinion based.. i would say whichever you are most familiar with. I personally use seneca, I have found that many of the modules are kind of outdated or not well tested but I end up not needing them at all, but the simplicity in creating multiple microservices/plugins work together is what make me choose it over others.

Answer (score -1):

[Moleculer](https://github.com/ice-services/moleculer) is a newbie microservices framework for NodeJS. You can try it on [Runkit](https://runkit.com/icebob/moleculer-quick-start) too.